# How can I use the output of a rand function, simulating 2 die rolls?

Tags: c++, random

I created 2 functions, each function will roll a dice, then I output the result of each dice in the main function. How can I add the results of each dice together? (I made a comment on the line in the main function)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

int diceroll1();
int diceroll2();

int main() {


    cout << "you rolled a.\n";
    cout << diceroll1(); cout << endl;
    cout << "and a\n";
    cout << diceroll2(); cout << endl;
    cout << "for a total of:\n";
    cout << diceroll1 + diceroll2 // idk how to sum these two values, and output them, as they are going to be different values each time. 

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int diceroll1() {

    int roll1;
    srand(time(0));
    const int numberOfRolls = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRolls; i++) {

        roll1 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
        return roll1;


    }

}
int diceroll2() {

    int roll2;
    srand(1+time(0));
    const int numberOfRolls = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRolls; i++) {

        roll2 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
        return roll2;

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) When you see two functions with identical logic, you don't need two functions.  You need a single function and to call it two times.  2) Never ever ever reseed the random number source multiple times in your program.  Putting `srand` at the beginning of your function reseeds every time you call the function, which is a huge no-no!

Comment: yeah, i figured out how to combine the two functions while using the same seed. do you know why its not okay to reseed?

Comment: Pseudo random number generators are deterministic algorithms which cycle through their state.  The seed is no more (and no less) than an entry point to the cycle.  It's the sequence of values that's meant to mimic randomness rather than any individual value.  If you keep reseeding, you're interfering with the carefully constructed distributional behavior.  Even worse, if time is used as the basis of the seed then modern computers can reseed multiple times in the same "tick", which produces the same seed, which produces the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
diceroll1() + diceroll2()
```

since the compiler sees it as value that diceroll1() returns + value of diceroll2();